# Sorting Dates in a pandas DataFrame while maintaining the order in the minute

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, datetime

I have a pandas Dataframe which contains dates as its first column, which I want to sort.
What happens is that it sorts by date but shuffles the order of the minutes, like this is the original text file for example.

```
12/20/20, 16:38 - d
12/20/20, 16:37 - a
12/20/20, 16:37 - b
12/20/20, 16:37 - c
```

After converting to pandas datetime, making columns, creating dataframe, sorting that dataframe, I exported it again to another text file where it now looks like this.

```
12/20/20, 16:37 - c
12/20/20, 16:37 - a
12/20/20, 16:37 - b
12/20/20, 16:38 - d
```

It doesnt reverse the order, it just organizes it randomly, because I do not have the seconds for this data, the multiple lines which have the same limit get shuffled, which should not happen.

My Solution to the problem currently is to somehow assign a special index to all the individual lines that have the same value of time, upto the minute, and then after the dataframe is sorted with date, to sort it again with those indices.

it would look like this:

```
12/20/20, 16:38 - d - 1
12/20/20, 16:37 - a - 1
12/20/20, 16:37 - b - 2
12/20/20, 16:37 - c - 3
```

Then when I get this result again after sorting,

```
12/20/20, 16:37 - c - 3
12/20/20, 16:37 - a - 1
12/20/20, 16:37 - b - 2
12/20/20, 16:38 - d - 1
```

I can sort it with the extra index to get the required result.

```
12/20/20, 16:37 - a - 1
12/20/20, 16:37 - b - 2
12/20/20, 16:37 - c - 3
12/20/20, 16:38 - d - 1
```

But I realize this is tedius, and was hoping there is a more elegant solution! Thanks!

Comment: what if you add `kind='stable'` to the `sort_values` call?

Comment: Yes that works!, also kind  =  'mergesort' also works

Answer (score 0):

I just had to change the method of sorting, as quick sort is the default method of sort_values() and changing it to 'stable' or 'mergesort' would fix this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).